# Pass array from one function to another

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing

This is what I want to do:

```
int randomtal(void){
  int loop;
  int tal[10];
  srand(time(0));

  for(loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++){
      tal[loop] = rand() % 10+1;
  }
  return tal;
}


int upp1(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   int Tal[10];
   Tal[] = randomtal();
   return 0;
}
```

Simply the `randomtal()` function generates 10 numbers and put these in an array. I then want to pass this array to the `upp1()` function and put these in the `Tal` array. Basically make a copy of `tal[]` in function `randomtal()` and pass this to `Tal` in function `upp1()`.

Comment: What is `Tal[] = randomtal();` ?

Comment: Tal[] is the array I want to store all numbers in function upp1 and randomtal(); is me calling that function to generate numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your function to accept an array as a parameter.  And because an array as a function argument is actually a pointer to the first element of the array, changes to the array in the function are reflected in the caller.

```
void randomtal(int tal[10]){
  int loop;
  srand(time(0));

  for(loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++){
      tal[loop] = rand() % 10+1;
  }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   int Tal[10];

   randomtal(Tal);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!